# Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when ‘hibernate.dialect’ not set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Spring 4.3.4 hibernate 5.1.15
As part of hibernate from 3 to 5.1.15, I came across this error.

The normal application starts works but if I run DBTest with the same setting, it isn't working.

I have quiet a few issues on similar lines but I am very clean on what could be the issue

I tried different ways of configuration from hibernate end.
https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernateexception-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null-when-hibernate-dialect-not-set

```
<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
                hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
                hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
                hibernate.generate_statistics=false
                hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries=true
                hibernate.connection.datasource=java:/onaro_pool
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.company.entity" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
</bean>


@Bean
    @Lazy
    BasicDataSource initDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(this.databasePlatform.getSetupConnectionURL());
        dataSource.setDefaultTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
        dataSource.setUsername(ProductProperties.getMysqlRootUser());
        dataSource.setPassword(ProductProperties.getMysqlRootPassword());
        dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

I am extending org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean to create CustomHibernateSesionFactoryBean

```
@Override
public MetadataSources getMetadataSources() {
    this.metadataSourcesAccessed = true;
    if (this.metadataSources == null) {
        BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder();
        ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = (ResourcePatternResolver) getResourceLoader();
        if (resourcePatternResolver != null) {
            builder = builder.applyClassLoader(resourcePatternResolver.getClassLoader()).applyIntegrator(eventListenerIntegrator);
        }
        this.metadataSources = new MetadataSources(builder.build());
    }
    return this.metadataSources;
}

@Override
protected SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sfb) {

    if (!DatabasePlatform.INVENTORY_SCHEMA.equals(DatabasePlatform.DEFAULT_INVENTORY_SCHEMA)) {
        logger.info("Overriding inventory schema name to %s", DatabasePlatform.INVENTORY_SCHEMA);
        Metadata metadata = getMetadataSources().getMetadataBuilder().build();
        Collection<PersistentClass> entityBindings = metadata.getEntityBindings();
        /* do customization */

    }
    return (this.bootstrapExecutor != null ? sfb.buildSessionFactory(this.bootstrapExecutor) : sfb.buildSessionFactory());

}
```

Normal application start works but Dbtest is not working i am getting the below mentioned error.

```
com.company.project.webui.package.SampleDbTest > testAggregationSummary STANDARD_OUT
    2019-01-28 22:49:41,437 INFO  [Test worker] [c.n.d.p.p.DatabasePlatform] Using database jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/product?cachePrepStmts=true&prepStmtCacheSize=1000&prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=1000
    2019-01-28 22:49:42,234 INFO  [Test worker] [c.n.d.p.h.projectHibernateSessionFactoryBean] Overriding inventory schema name to mock_sample_view
    2019-01-28 22:49:42,271 WARN  [Test worker] [o.h.e.j.c.i.ConnectionProviderInitiator] HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
    2019-01-28 22:49:42,273 WARN  [Test worker] [o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The application must supply JDBC connections
    2019-01-28 22:49:42,275 WARN  [Test worker] [o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityDeleter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'session'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateSessionProxyFactoryBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/database-test-support.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    2019-01-28 22:49:42,278 ERROR [Test worker] [o.s.t.c.TestContextManager] Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@6c004124] to prepare test instance [com.company.project.webui.package.SampleDbTest@37b459ad]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
        at com.company.project.da.test.DatabaseTestSupport$SpringStyleTestRunner.runChild(DatabaseTestSupport.java:162)
        at com.company.project.da.test.DatabaseTestSupport$SpringStyleTestRunner.runChild(DatabaseTestSupport.java:147)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:108)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:146)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:128)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityDeleter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'session'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateSessionProxyFactoryBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/database-test-support.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:592)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at com.company.project.common.test.spring.AnnotationConfigContextLoader.loadContext(AnnotationConfigContextLoader.java:60)
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:70)
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
        ... 49 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateSessionProxyFactoryBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/database-test-support.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:592)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589)
        ... 64 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/database-test-support.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589)
        ... 77 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
        at com.company.project.persist.hibernate.projectHibernateSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(projectHibernateSessionFactoryBean.java:108)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
        ... 87 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
        ... 102 common frames omitted
Gradle Test Executor 1 finished executing tests.

com.company.project.webui.package.SampleDbTest > testAggregationSummary FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

        Caused by:
        org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityDeleter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'session'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateSessionProxyFactoryBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/database-test-support.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

            Caused by:
            org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateSessionProxyFactoryBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/database-test-support.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

                Caused by:
                org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/database-test-support.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

                    Caused by:
                    org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

                        Caused by:
                        org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set.
```

- I am using spring-core (Don't have explicit spring boot in the application).
- While searching for a similar issue, I came across "Hibernate can determine the correct dialect to use automatically, but in order to do this, it needs a live connection to the database". I have injected data source bean not sure why session factory isn't taking it?
- I am extending LocalSessionFactoryBean, should i be extending something else?
- What is the best place to explicitly set config with the property? config.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT_KEY, getDialect());

Answer (score -1):

The issue was due to the way i was using overriding getMetadataSources.

When i override LocalSessionFactoryBean i am getting this issue.